# IBP Python SDK functionality for invoking chaincode transactions

Tags: blockchain, ibm-blockchain

Looking at the current IBP Python SDK ( https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibp-python-sdk ) I can't find any calls for invoking chaincode transactions (adding data in the ledger and querying it). Will this functionality be added later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SDK is only for the managing of the IBM Blockchain Platform itself and is not an SDK for interacting with a Hyperledger Fabric network created on IBM Blockchain Platform. You should look to the various hyperlegdger fabric SDKs themselves for that capability. IBM provides documentation about this which you can find here
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/blockchain?topic=blockchain-ibp-console-app

Note that it doesn't list the hyperledger fabric Python SDK because it's not recommended for use with IBM Blockchain Platform.

Comment: I am trying to interract with a Hyperledger Fabric network hosted on IBM cloud from C++ code. The available SDKs are not well suitable for this: for Java  you have to use JNI and include the whole JVM inside the process (too heavy-weight); for node.js you write a client app that interacts with the blockchain and exposes a REST API to be called by the C++ code (this is the way I am doing it now) but this has the downside that you have to secure the node.js REST server in turn. GO is a no-go. Python would seem like a decent light-weight way of interacting with blockchain by forking scripts ...

Comment: couldn't you do the same with node.js ?